# Dovecot doesn't start

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot

I've installed [Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/postfix.html) and it works correctly. I've installed [Dovecot](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/dovecot-server.html) and set its configurations too. But when I try `service dovecot start` it terminates on startup. In syslog I have:

```
Nov 19 10:54:02 servername kernel: [2510855.242291] init: dovecot main process (29159) terminated with status 89
Nov 19 10:54:02 servername kernel: [2510855.242305] init: dovecot respawning too fast, stopped
```

I had installed Dovecot and it was working fine, then I changed my configurations, purge Dovecot and Postfix and after that installed them again. I copied default configurations from `/usr/share/doc/dovecot-core/example-config/` and changed necessary configurations as they're mentioned in tutorials. Now I have this problem. What can I do?

Comment: log excerpt is too short

Comment: @Kondybas the rest of log is same,ierminates on startup, trys to respawn and loops.

Comment: Most probable a syntax error in one of the config files you changed. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1655875

Comment: @douggro Thanks man. My problem wasn't same, but I could find the solution anyway.

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, post it as an answer. Helps those that may experience the same problem down the road.

Comment: @douggro done ;)

Answer (score 3):

First check syntax of all configuration files in `/etc/dovecot/` and `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/`.

Then check `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` for `ssl_cert` and `ssl_key` paths. Check the files that are given, If they're not exist, use `mkcert.sh` to create ssl key and certificate. You can find all information [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/CertificateCreation). Download [`dovecot-openssl.cnf`](http://dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-openssl.cnf) and modify values. Download [`mkcert.sh`](http://dovecot.org/doc/mkcert.sh) and run it.
After that change `10-ssl.conf`:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
```

Restart dovecot.

Comment: Yep, this was my issue ... I stupidly didn't create the SSL certs, and I can confirm that it only gives the vague error of `terminated with status 89`